# How to find element and get row or column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'd like to find a way to look up a value in a table and return the name of the column or row. Anyone who can help me?

Apps Scripts ?

[image: table where search value and return row or column]

I found an easy way with the formulas:

For X =INDEX($A$1:$F$2, MIN(IF(B2:F6="31", MATCH(COLUMN(B2:F6), COLUMN(B2:F6)), "")))

For Y =INDEX($A$1:$F$2, MIN(IF(B2:F6="31", MATCH(ROW(B2:F6), ROW(B2:F6)), "")))

Does anyone know how to deal with google apps scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement the bellow code using a [custom menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus), this will prompt you the number you want to find and show the results:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Search', 'lookUp')
      .addToUi();
}

function lookUp() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg=sh.getDataRange();
  const vs=rg.getValues();
  const r=SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Search", "Enter Number", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
  const v=r.getResponseText();
  vs.forEach(function(r,i){
    r.forEach(function(c,j){
      if(c==v) {
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(Utilities.formatString('row name:%s,col name: %s',vs[i][0],vs[0][j]));
      }
    });
  });
}
```

If you want to insert the values in the sheet, you can use [setValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue) method.